# How to use own apps that contains in-app billing in android?

Tags: android, in-app

I have created a free app that includes a in-app billing in order to unlock some features
and I need to use it. I need to buy it?
I have another app, that's not freeware and i have introduced my email address in the developer console in order to use it for free, but it doesn't work with in-app billing. why? I need to purchase my own app? :crazy:
thank's

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to buy your own stuff :)

See [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)